# Terraform for AWS: How to have multiple events per S3 bucket filtered on object path?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

My understanding is that when configuring an [S3 bucket notification](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/s3_bucket_notification.html) with Terraform we can only configure a single notification per S3 bucket:

```
NOTE: S3 Buckets only support a single notification configuration. Declaring multiple
ws_s3_bucket_notification resources to the same S3 Bucket will cause a perpetual difference in
configuration. See the example "Trigger multiple Lambda functions" for an option.
```

The application uses a single S3 bucket as a data repository, i.e. when JSON files land there they trigger a lambda which submits a corresponding batch job to ingest from the file into a database.

This works well when we have a single developer deploying the infrastructure, but with multiple developers each time one of us runs `terraform apply` then it updates the only/single notification for the bucket, overwriting the resource's previous settings.

What is the best practice for utilizing S3 buckets for notifications? Are they best configured/created per Terraform workspace, and/or how are the buckets managed to allow for simultaneous developers standing up/down infrastructure resources using a common S3 bucket via `terraform apply`, etc.? Must you use one bucket per workspace for this use case, as suggested by the docs?

The current Terraform I have for the S3 notification (the code that allows for overwriting with the latest configuration):

```
data "aws_s3_bucket" "default" {
  bucket = var.bucket
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "allow_bucket_execution" {
  statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromS3Bucket"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = var.lambda_function_name
  principal     = "s3.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = data.aws_s3_bucket.default.arn
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "bucket_notification" {
  bucket = data.aws_s3_bucket.default.bucket

  lambda_function {
    lambda_function_arn = var.lambda_function_arn
    events              = ["s3:ObjectCreated:*"]
    filter_prefix       = var.namespace
    filter_suffix       = ".json"
  }
}
```

The `namespace` variable is passed in as `"${local.env}-${terraform.workspace}"`, with `local.env` as "dev", "uat", "prod", etc.

How can we modify the Terraform code above to allow for multiple notifications per S3 bucket (essentially one per Terraform workspace), or can it just not be done? If not then how is this best handled? Should I just use a bucket per workspace using a namespace variable like above as the S3 bucket name, and have it updated accordingly to the production bucket at deployment?

Comment: I had a very similar problem and this answered it perfectly: https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/making-an-aws-s3-bucket-with-multiple-event-notifications-for-multiple-sqs-queues/59220

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options you have depending on your needs:

- Create one bucket per env and workspace. Then the mentioned limitation of terraforms `aws_s3_bucket_notification` should no longer be an issue. I could imagine that the process you use to write to your bucket will then still only write to one bucket you specify. To solve this issue you could think about forwarding any objects uploaded to one "master" bucket to all other buckets (either with a lambda, itself triggered by a `aws_s3_bucket_notification` or probably by [bucket replication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/replication.html)).
- create one bucket per env and deploy the `aws_s3_bucket_notification` without workspaces. Then you do no longer have the advantages of workspaces. But this might be a reasonable compromise between number of buckets and usability
- keep just this one bucket, keep envs and workspaces, but deploy the `aws_s3_bucket_notification` resource only once (probably together with the bucket). Then this one `aws_s3_bucket_notification` resource would need to include the rules for all environment and workspaces.

It really depends on your situation what fits best. If those `aws_s3_bucket_notification` rarely change at all, and most changes are done in the lambda function, the last option might be the best. If you regularly want to change the `aws_s3_bucket_notification` and events to listen on, one of the other options might be more suitable.

Comment: Why is this a limitation? Seems like an artificial constraint. I have an env with many buckets, each with with many event notifications pointing to many different SQS queues. If it can be done via the AWS Console GUI, why can't terraform do it?